# If $H\le G$, when can we embed $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ into $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, whether an automorphism of $H$ can always be extended to an automorphism of $G$, inducing an embedding of ${\rm Aut}(H)$ into ${\rm Aut}(G)$?

If not, what are some counter-examples? Under which conditions on $G$ and $H$, it is true?

Comment: This question needs some interpretation. An automorphism of $H$ isn't an automorphism of $G$, as it has a different domain, so the group of automorphisms of $H$ isn't even a subset of the group of automorphisms of $G$, let alone a subgroup. So, what are you really asking?

Comment: While you're thinking about it, you might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477524/characteristic-subgroups-and-automorphisms and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478384/characteristic-subgroups-and-automorphisms and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060195/on-automorphisms-of-groups-which-extend-as-automorphisms-to-every-larger-group and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100687/on-group-automorphism-of-subgroup-a-group-g (which is an exact duplicate of part of your question).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: thanks a lot for the references. I understand your point. What I mean is when an automorphism of H can be extended to an automorphism of G.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo: Thanks for your help! Let h ∈ H, and g ∈ G \ H. Then g.h ∈ G \ H. Hence,  ′(g.h) = g.h . But, ′(g.h) = ′(g). ′(h) = g. (h) . This implies: (h) = h  for all h∈ H, which may not be the case. So I guess the  ′  you defined would not work.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work.

Comment: Another earlier question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462822/questions-about-group-of-automorphisms/). For an example, consider $G = D_8$, $H = C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: You should edit your post, so it says what you mean, clearly and unambiguously.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Done.

Comment: @Shaun: Done. Thanks for the suggestion; I will post the second part as a separate question.

Comment: Good. But the title still has it wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to correct the title.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You can always change it yourself….

Comment: @Jacob, sure, I could. But I don't think it's too much to ask of people posting here asking for help, that when an error is pointed out to them, that they fix it themselves.

Comment: So, Dey, have the links users have posted helped you to see an answer to your question?